# What will be the uncertainty in $\mu_0$ under the new SI scheme?

Tags: electromagnetism, error-analysis, si-units, metrology

As you may be aware, a new SI system is likely to be adopted in November 2018 (see https://www.nist.gov/si-redefinition/kilogram-introduction).

Whilst the speed of light remains a fixed quantity and hence $\epsilon_0 \mu_0$ remains fixed, the definition of the kg and Ampere will change such that $\mu_0$ will have an experimental uncertainty.

What is the current level of that uncertainty?

I note [Uncertainty of permittivity of vacuum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108626/), which is clearly linked. But I also note that all of the answers there are based on the soon to be superseded current system in which there is no uncertainty in $\mu_0$ or $\epsilon_0$ and are therefore about to become incorrect!

Comment: According to this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(electromagnetism) have $\mu_0 =  4 \pi \times 1.000 000 000 82 (20) 10^{−7} H m^{−1}$ (reference to experiment given).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the new system of units the electron charge, speed of light and Planck's constant all assume defined values.

The permeability of vacuum or "magnetic constant", $\mu_0$ can be written as
$$ \mu_0 = \frac{2h}{e^2 c}\alpha,$$
where $\alpha$ is the fine structure constant.

According to [NIST](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?alph), the fine structure constant has a value of
$$ \alpha = (7.2973525664 \pm 0.0000000017) \times 10^{-3}$$
corresponding to a relative precision of $2.3\times 10^{-10}$.

I assume then, that this will be the relative precision with which $\mu_0$ is known after the re-definition.

Comment: Yes, this is right. +1

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The full roster is given [in this Wikipedia table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposed_redefinition_of_SI_base_units#Uncertainty_of_fundamental_physical_constants).

Comment: ... and, even better, this is mentioned explicitly in the changeover resolution (as linked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/440693/8563)).